# In what order generated IDs are returned for jdbcOperations.execute statement with RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS marker?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

I didn't find any mentioning of an order of generated IDs which are returned in jdbcOperations.execute method in the official documentation. Although it's very crucial for me to know the order.

I have a method which accepts a list of objects without IDs which should be populated after the generation. If generated IDs are returned in the same order as in the list of objects, then I can just iterate over two lists and assign IDs to the objects. Otherwise I need to do another a select query using returned IDs which will affect my performance.

Here's the example of such method:

```
public static List<Long> executeBatchInsert(final ParsedSql parsedSql, final SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs, JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {

    if (batchArgs.length <= 0) {
        return Lists.newArrayList();
    }

    String sqlToUse = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, batchArgs[0]);

    BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss = new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            Object[] values = NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, batchArgs[i], null);
            int[] columnTypes = NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlTypeArray(parsedSql, batchArgs[i]);
            setStatementParameters(values, ps, columnTypes);
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return batchArgs.length;
        }
    };

    return jdbcOperations.execute(
            con -> con.prepareStatement(sqlToUse, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS),
            (PreparedStatementCallback<List<Long>>) ps -> {
                int batchSize = pss.getBatchSize();
                for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
                    pss.setValues(ps, i);
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                ps.executeBatch();

                List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();

                // Here I need to be sure that keys order is the same as in SqlParameterSource[] 
                ResultSet keys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                while (keys.next()) {
                    result.add(keys.getLong(1));
                }
                return result;
            });
}
```

Comment: I suspect that there is no guaranteed order and it all depends on the DB implementation.

Comment: Be aware that support of `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` with batch execution is not required by the JDBC specification, but generally I would expect, if a driver supports it, that the order is in the same order as the batch. So the first generated keys row matches with the first set of values of the batch.